# How to plot the interval of polynomials roots in scilab

Tags: scilab, polynomials

We were given lab work with either MatLab or Scilab and pretty much no guidance on how these programs work. And i'am stuck on this exercise: Find polynomial **y(x)** roots, find the interval to which the roots belong and plot the graph. 
The equation would be: **y(x)=x^5-2**.
I found the roots myself ( at least I think these are roots ):

```
 x  = 


   x


p=x^5-2
 p  = 

       5
  -2 +x 

r=real(r)
 r  = 

  -0.9293165
  -0.9293165
   0.3549673
   0.3549673
   1.1486984
```

So how do I plot graph with this and write the interval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean real roots ? There is only one real root here. You can obtain these roots and plot the graph of the polynomial (and denote the root location) on [0,2] with the following statements:

```
x = poly(0, "x")
r = roots(x^5-2)
X = linspace(0,2,100)
plot(X, X.^5-2, X, 0*X, r(5), 0, 'x')

 r  = 

  -0.9293165 + 0.675188i
  -0.9293165 - 0.675188i
   0.3549673 + 1.0924771i
   0.3549673 - 1.0924771i
   1.1486984
```

[image]

Comment: My guess is that the real root is "1.14", But how do I graph this polynomial? I'am really confused about this exercise and really just guessing what they could want from me

Comment: I have edited my answer to add the statements plotting the polynomial.